# Input string not in the correct format when reading a text file into a 2d Array

Tags: c#, input, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read a text file into a 2d array. However I get an error of

> *Input string was not in the correct format.*

I have checked the text file and it is all as it should be and I cant see why this error is happening?

```
        int[,] numberMatrix = new int[10, 10];
        string[] split = null;

        for (int rowCount = 1; rowCount < 11; rowCount++)
        {
            int[] temp1DArray = new int[10];
            string fileLocation = "C:\\Week10\\one.txt";
            string textFile = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation);

            for (int columnCount = 1; columnCount < 11; columnCount++)
            {
                string delimStr = " ";
                char[] delimiter = delimStr.ToCharArray();
                //string fileLocation = "C:\\Week10\\1-100.txt";
                //string textFile = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation);
                for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
                {
                    split = textFile.Split(delimiter, x);
                }
            }

            for (int rowCount1 = 1; rowCount1 < 11; rowCount1++)
            {
                for (int columnCount = 1; columnCount < 11; columnCount++)
                {
                    numberMatrix[rowCount1 - 1, columnCount - 1]   =Convert.ToInt32(split.ElementAt(columnCount - 1));
                }
            }
        }

        for (int rowCount = 10; rowCount > 0; rowCount--)
        {
            for (int columnCount = 10; columnCount > 0; columnCount--)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numberMatrix[rowCount - 1, columnCount - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it says the error is on line 40

Comment: Which one is line 40? :)

Comment: give example of file contents and expected result

Comment: Debug your program and stop on that line 40. I guess this `Convert.ToInt32(split.ElementAt(columnCount - 1))` produce an error. Just check what is returned by `split.ElementAt(columnCount - 1)` Additionally, you should show a piece of your `one.txt`

Comment: it is just a grid 10 x 10 of numbers 1 - 100 and looking to print out the grid, the numbers are one space apart, from the error i assumed it would be a problem in the text file but looking at the file there doesnt seem to be anything wrong with it

Comment: the error seems to be when it reaches the end of the first line of text, so at 10 when it should go to the next line to 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ok, you haven't provided any file contents and exact Exception description (it can fire on any reason possible). I can give much more simple implementation for file parsing. I can't think of an answer, which will magically find the reason of why one number in your file can't be parsed to `int`

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\1.txt");
var options = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries;

int[][] numbers = lines.Select(line => line.Split(new[]{' '}, options)
                                           .Select(int.Parse)
                                           .ToArray())
                       .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                              numbers.Select(n => string.Join(" ", n))));
```

For file:

> ```
> 1 10 20 30 
> 4234 35 123 543
> 42 54 345 645
> ```

prints:

```
1 10 20 30
4234 35 123 543
42 54 345 645
```

If you need rectangle array `int[,]` use next code to parse it to.

```
int [,] numbersRect = new int[numbers.Length, numbers[0].Length];

for (int i = 0; i < numbersRect.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numbersRect.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        numbersRect[i,j] = numbers[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers I ran your code and its great. Must mean there is a problem in the nested loops. However I must agree that your code is so much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

From where I standing  split returns an array. And                                       numberMatrix[rowCount1 - 1, columnCount - 1]    is array element - not array itself.                                                                                             So  numberMatrix[rowCount1 - 1, columnCount - 1]   =Convert.ToInt32(split.ElementAt(columnCount - 1));  will fire an exception.
Also Convert.ToInt32 takes a single value not an array.